# Setting a variable using another variable in Rythm

Tags: java, html, servlets, template-engine, rythm

I have a Rythm template that looks like:

```
...Some HTML...
@get("title")
...Some More HTML...
```

And then I use it in another file, which is called from a Java Servlet. The file looks like:

```
@extends(../root.html)
@args String leTitle
@set(title = @leTitle)

Hello @leTitle !
```

Where, `leTitle` is given to this HTML file from the Servlet in `args`.

The variable `leTitle` is fine when used in the body, but when setting the `title` variable, it says:

```
org.rythmengine.exception.CompileException: Syntax error on token "@", delete this token
```

Removing it from the title makes things work. So, should the title be a static string? Or is there a way to initialise it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `@set(title = leTitle)`. No `@` before `leTitle`